# What public key to use when verifying JWT.io signature OneLogin ID Token

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, onelogin

I am trying to verify id_token I received from OneLogin OpenID Connect. I looked up online and everyone says I need to use a .pem file but how do I generate that file? I can use OpenSSL to generate it but which key to use when generating that .pem certificate? I have tried with client_id, client_secret. None of these work.

Can someone please help?

Please see the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OneLogin supports public key (RS256) encryption and you can find the public keys courtesy of the well.known endpoint OneLogin provides.

Ex. https://t3stc0.onelogin.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration

This URL (specific to your account) can also be found on the SSO tab of your application configuration.

From that endpoint you can get links to various details about the certs in various fields

```
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "issuer": "https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc",
  "jwks_uri": "https://t3stc0.onelogin.com/oidc/certs",
```

For more details on the specifics, check out the [OIDC spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html). I also *highly* recommend making your code be able to respond to changing keys as these keys are subject to change (I believe Google changes theirs daily!)

But any decent open source OIDC client *should* be able to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks @john! I am able to use that "jwks_uri" keys to verify using this library "jwk-to-pem". I was trying to see if I can verify it on jwt.io website. I'll try to convert that json to a pem format and verify. Thank you!